# How to use twitter api with multiple accounts like tweetdeck or hootsuite

Tags: twitter

i am trying to build a web app that everyone can manage their (multi)twitter accounts using it. i figured out authentication already so i don't have any problem with that. 
also using the rest api the app could manage accounts fully. 
but there is a problem called "rate limit". so there is also "streaming api" that allows you to receive informations real-time but limited count of users only.

my app's interface like tweetdeck or hootsuite. when user refresh a column, it querying from local db not twitter api. so i want to create a cron-job to insert/update/delete stuff in my db.

so far imo my app must use streaming api right? 
considering one browser manages 10+ twitter accounts, total online users 1000+ that means huge amount of data transfering.

here are my questions:
- how can i manage many accounts using one web-app escaping the twitter api limits?
- how tweetdeck or hootsuite figured out this?
- is "streaming api and lists" proper way to handle this situation?

thanks.

Comment: Tweetdeck is owned by Twitter. But for other big players I guess they got access to the [Site Streams api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/site). But "Site Streams is currently in a limited beta. Access is restricted to whitelisted accounts."

Comment: i noticed that thanks. also looking for an answer for "how do i get my app whitelisted?" so far no luck!

Comment: Fill the form https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?hl=en&formkey=dFBTbHZIMVhseUtqS2NkT283RTluX3c6MQ#gid=0